# How to interpret Index Error specific to my code

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have an index error problem that I would like to understand.

How do I interpret  `if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= len_axis or arr.min() < -len_axis):`?

Ie, I dont know which array it is referring to, ie `len(arr)` or `len_axis` in relation to my code.

Output:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-f9c0ccc07fa7> in <module>
----> 1 Engine_EO4(Input_Data)

<ipython-input-25-7d8bbce39c4d> in Engine_EO4(Input_Data)
    234                 col = i
    235                 row = y
--> 236                 j.append(ValveCover.iloc[row+6:,[col,col+1,col+2,col+5,col+6,col+9, col+10]])
    237                 break
    238     df=j[0].astype(float).round(6)

F:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1760                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1761                     pass
-> 1762             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1763         else:
   1764             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

F:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2065     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):
   2066 
-> 2067         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2068         try:
   2069             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

F:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    701                 raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    702             try:
--> 703                 self._validate_key(k, i)
    704             except ValueError:
    705                 raise ValueError(

F:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   2007             # check that the key does not exceed the maximum size of the index
   2008             if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= len_axis or arr.min() < -len_axis):
-> 2009                 raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
   2010         else:
   2011             raise ValueError(f"Can only index by location with a [{self._valid_types}]")

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Comment: You are storing multiple values at once into `j` variable. Append takes only one element. just debug you valueCover.iloc thing how many elements it's is giving you just check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call on an index that is larger than the max length of your array or smaller than the min length of your array.

The error is showing the lineage of packages that are called upon to execute iloc. If you look at the dimensions of your `ValveCover` dataframe, and compare them to the indices you're trying to call in iloc, you should be able to locate the discrepancy.

Comment: I used ValveCover.shape which returned `(235,37)`. how do I **'compare them to the indices'**?

Comment: i believe the code which has a break line is not working which leads to this error. Struggling to find the correct position of break in the for loop

Comment: It's this line that appears to be giving you the error `j.append(ValveCover.iloc[row+6:,[col,col+1,col+2,col+5,col+6,col+9, col+10]])`. The colon denotes a slice ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)) so I would check your `row` and `col` values against those dimensions.